# Can I continue to eat a cereal my cat ate out of?

Tags: food-safety, saliva, zoonotic-diseases, contaminate, zoonotic-viruses

So this morning I eating cereal (lucky charms) and the batteries to my remote were running low so I went to go change them, leaving my cereal in my room. When I came back my kitten around 3 or 4 months was licking the milk from my cereal. His paws weren't in it though. I really don't want to waste food. So is it safe if I just continue eating it? He was only there for 15 seconds at most. I'm typing this at my computer with my cereal behind me on a tall stool.

https://i.ytimg.com/vi/j6aQx0ViHG0/maxresdefault.jpg

Somewhat what I walked into this morning but this is not my cat.
(Not a picture of my cat)

Comment: I'd be more worried about humans eating my cereal. Really.

Answer (score 3):

This really isn't any different from asking if it is safe to share food with another person after watching them eat from the same bowl.  If you have a weak immune system, as with anything else, it is probably better to not share saliva with pets or humans.

Depending on your comfort zone, there shouldn't be any issues though if you wanted to continue eating.  The only stopping factor is really if you find it unpleasant or not.  I know plenty of people who share a glass of water with their pets, for me, I wouldn't cause I don't find it appealing.

So in the end it's really a matter of choice to you, but it is worth noting if you have a weak immune system to not share saliva in general.